# Resize a disk image

Tags: partitioning, qemu, fdisk

I'm having trouble trying to increase the size of an ubuntu disk image. I know that I need to perform the following steps -at least-:

```
$ # 1. resize the image using qemu-img
$ qemu-img resize linux-x86.img +12G
$ # this step succeeded
$ # 2. mount, chroot
$ sudo mount -o loop,offset=32256 linux-x86.img /mnt
$ sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
$ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
$ cd /mnt
$ sudo chroot .
```

Now the following steps are performed within chroot:

```
$ df -h
df: cannot read table of mounted file systems: No such file or directory
$ # fix this error 
$ cp /proc/mounts /etc/mtab
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0            496M  458M   13M  98% /
udev                  2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
```

You can see that the available space is only 13M, even though I have increased the size of the image to 12 more GBs.

I tried starting fdisk, but the partition table was empty:

```
$ fdisk /dev/loop0
Device contains neither a valid DOS partition table, nor Sun, SGI or OSF disklabel
Building a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xa95b4787.
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
After that, of course, the previous content won't be recoverable.


The number of cylinders for this disk is set to 1631.
There is nothing wrong with that, but this is larger than 1024,
and could in certain setups cause problems with:
1) software that runs at boot time (e.g., old versions of LILO)
2) booting and partitioning software from other OSs
   (e.g., DOS FDISK, OS/2 FDISK)
Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 4 will be corrected by w(rite)

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/loop0: 13.4 GB, 13421609472 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1631 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa95b4787

      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Command (m for help):
```

Here is /etc/mtab for your info:

```
/dev/loop0 / ext2 rw,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=2010936k,nr_inodes=502734,mode=755 0 0
```

Also, here is the output of "uname -a":

```
Linux ubuntu 4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 15:32:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you got the disk part of the resize down. What you didn't do was resize the partition within, which is a separate step from resizing the filesystem. The reason fdisk isn't finding any partitions is because it doesn't have access to the whole "disk". Basically, what you did was fdisk /dev/sd?1, when you need to fdisk /dev/sd?, or, in your case, fdisk linux-x86.img. You should do this before chrooting as well.

Something that will help you combine the resize of the partition and the filesystem into one step...

```
$ sudo udisksctl loop-setup -f linux-x86.img
Mapped file linux-x86.img as /dev/loop0.
$ sudo gparted /dev/loop0
```

You can then also mount /dev/loop0p1, or whatever, instead of finding the start byte of the partition and mounting that offset.

Comment: You can truncate the disk image following the instructions here : https://softwarebakery.com/shrinking-images-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

Remove the loop device with this

```
sudo udisksctl loop-delete -b /dev/loop0
```